# Hex to decimal converter (ESN Algo)

Tags: delphi, decimal

How to make conversion like on this page?
http://www.esnconverter.com/index.php?esn=88888888

I tried to make like this but the result is wrong

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(sender: TObject);
begin
memo1.Lines.Add (IntToStr(StrToInt('$'+Edit1.text)));
end;
```

Comment: Well, what is the specification? What is the function meant to do? In what way does your code fail to meet expectations?

Comment: "Conversion like on this page" is not description of the problem. Describe please what you need to calculate and what is the problem. For conversion to/from hex you can use functions HexToBin/BinToHex, there a lot of examples on SO how to use them. And you should understand what is it - hexadecimal: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: Sir @DavidHeffernan I don't know the formula how it's calculate:  Hex ESN 88888888
Result is = Decimal ESN 13608947848. While my conevrter show result -2004318072

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn aha, but it's about different thing. It is like this https://www.google.com/search?q=ESN+%22Electronic+Serial+Number%22
My brother ask me to make this calculator for him.

Comment: You have to tell us what these things are, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: voted to close. Maybe the brother should show more effort before asking this.

Comment: The hexadecimal representation of 13608947848 is obviously not 88888888. You'll need to go find out what the real conversion algorithm is *before* you can expect help implementing or debugging it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_serial_number)

> For the decimal format the first three digits are the decimal
>   representation of the first 8 bits (between 000 and 255 inclusive) and
>   the next 8 digits are derived from the remaining 24 bits and will be
>   between 00000000 and 16777215 inclusive

```
Memo1.Lines.Add( Format('%.3d%.8d',
  [StrToInt(('$' + Copy(Edit1.Text, 1, 2))),
  StrToInt(('$' + Copy(Edit1.Text, 3, 6)))]));
```

The above gives the same output with that page, however, I don't know anything about an ESN.

Comment: The index position in Copy() is off by 1.

Comment: @LURD - No. Why do you think so?

Comment: First item in a string has index 1. Try with `01234567` and compare the result with the converter linked in the question.

Comment: @LURD - Hm, so when I put 0 it starts with 1. I see, thanks!